# Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться с метафорой

Tags: грамотная-речь, этимология, метафора

Пишу песню об отношениях с девушками. Прошу вас, не корите меня за фривольность. Заинтересовался одной метафорой, но не знаю, насколько логично ее применение. Привожу вам следующую выдержку:

> Ты знаешь, что ты тоже одержима
> Ем тебя без остатка
> Самая сладкая
> И ведь я так падок
> На тебя
>
> Но не будь так тороплива
> Ты думала, всё серьезно, думала всё не фальшиво?
> Ведь твои бедра
> Стали в нашей любви лейтмотивом.

Как вы полагаете, уместна ли в данном случае метафора с лейтмотивом? Можно ли употребить такое слово? Логично ли это? Я отталкиваюсь от того, что лейтмотив в соответствии с определением, которое дает словарь Ожегова - основная тема музыкального произведения. Таким образом, пытаюсь намекнуть здесь на то, что именно прелести девушки заставили меня построить с ней отношения (естественно, это не соответствует действительности).

Уместно ли это с филологической точки зрения? Заранее благодарю!

Answer (score 1):

Лейтмотив встречается не только в музыке. Вообще, это нечто, к чему мы будем снова и снова возвращаться в процессе чего-то. Если вы говорите, что бёдра девушки были лейтмотивом в отношениях, то значит, что вы постоянно акцентировали на них внимание.
Вы же хотите сказать нечто другое. В вашем случае уместнее сказать, что бёдра стали катализатором отношений.

Comment: Катализатор в первую очередь термин из химии. Как метафора он неуместен. Особенно в поэзии.

Comment: Я считаю, что это субъективно. Стихотворение стихотворению рознь.